# SQL complicated join query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `match(id.match, date, home, away)` and `team(id. team, name)`.  In `match` `home` and `away` are foreign keys to the `team id`. In my query, I want an output record with `date` of `match,` and `name` of these two teams.

I have tried:

```
SELECT m.date, m.home, m.away, t.name 
FROM `match` m
JOIN team t ON m.home = t.id_team 
ORDER BY m.date
```

But this outputs two records instead of one. Is it possible to do what I want with sql or I should just change the table's design?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.. else its difficult to predict what you are looking after.

Comment: What is the relationship of both tables? 1:1, 1:N, N:M ? we need more details to provide an specific answer.

Comment: In general, try to avoid using reserved words as table/column identifiers. It just causes a headache.

Comment: There's no sensible reason wjy this would output more records than expected. To get both teams, join the teams table twice, with a different alias each time.

Comment: Formatted and fixed typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did 'deeper' research and find out the answer. Earlier i just asked wrong question. Thanks everyone for contribution!

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT m.date, m.home, m.away, t.name AS homename, te.name AS awayname
FROM `match` m 
JOIN team t ON m.home = t.id_team 
JOIN team te 
ON m.away = te.id_team ORDER BY m.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a many to one relationship between your tables.

This might work depending on the table values:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT m.date, m.home, m.away, t.name 
 FROM   `match` m JOIN 
       team t ON m.home = t.id_team 
 ORDER BY m.date
```